# Keep installer from installing Nvidia drivers but install other "optional" software

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, ubiquity

I have an old HP Pavilion laptop I use as a testbed so I am constantly installing and uninstalling systems on it.

It has NVIDIA Geforce 8300 graphics which are no longer supported ([nvidia-304 (304.137) missing in Ubuntu 18.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1763648)) but the installer still installs the 340 Nvidia driver which doesn't work and hangs the system on first boot. The latest example of this is the Ubuntu MATE 20.04 installer. So I have to boot into recovery and purge the drivers. I would like to skip this step if possible.

How can I prevent the installer from "proactively" installing Nvidia drivers for me? Is it the box you check on the installer screen here? If so, is there a way to have all the other stuff installed here **except** the video drivers?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply uncheck the

> [ ] Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats

during installation.

Then on first boot install codecs by

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Optionally you can visit Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and check 5th tab named *Additional Drivers*.

---

But personally I would recommend to use previous Ubuntu MATE version with fully-supported Nvidia driver on this laptop.

Comment: Thanks, great info. I usually wait a day before accepting.  `nouveau` is good enough for this testbed system. I'm actually experimenting to see if I can make a MATE desktop look close to an existing Lubuntu 18.04 desktop to ease a household member's transition to 20.04

Comment: I remembered that Nouveau in the 12.04-era caused overheating of my GT425M. Newer versions of driver has better power-related fuctions, I hope. But be careful. About look-and-feel - do not forget to check desktop panel layouts in MATE Tweak or MATE Welcome :)

Comment: You are right. The generic driver does not control the heating nearly as well as the nvidia ones. I actually patched the 304 driver manually and got it to work on this laptop back when I used it as a normal pc.